# Reset id sequence or update id on Grails Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails

In Grails 1.3.7, I have a code that filters objects by ID and I need to test that

The domain class has a sequence

```
static mapping = {
id generator: 'sequence', params[sequence: 'seq_shipping_service']
}
```

In the test, the object is created several times and I need the identifier to be 11 in all the tests and even though, it deletes the whole database between every test, it doesn't reset the sequence. So I would get a superior ID

```
foo = createFoo()
foo.id = 11l
foo.save () //This gets error
```

My ideas are
1) Reset somehow the id sequence so it's everytime the same number between tests
2) Set somehow the id

I don't know if I make myself clear

Comment: Can you try setting this in mapping for id ` id generator:'assigned'`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I need to do something like this I:

create an object mother to spawn all required objects (i.e. foo.id == 11)

use Groovy SQL to insert data into database. In your case:

```
public class BlahBlahTest extends Specification {
   DataSource dataSource

   def setup () {
      new Sql(dataSource).exec ("insert into blablah (11, ...)")
   }
...
```

Obviously you could do anything else there - for example recreate the sequence to start with 11.

Comment: How would I recreate the sequence?

Comment: On Oracle - drop sequence seq; create sequence seq start with 11; not sure about other databases.